# discord.js Read data from URL

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I can't figure out how to read data from a url like get the text from it such as

```
url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/k4dEkXCz"
```

andI want to read data from it like what it says

Comment: Everyone I Found An Answer

    const Discord = require("discord.js");
let snekfetch = require("snekfetch")

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
let url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/k4dEkXCz"
snekfetch.get(url).then(r => console.log(decodeURIComponent(r.body)));
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "test"
}

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let snekfetch = require("snekfetch")

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
let url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/k4dEkXCz"
snekfetch.get(url).then(r => console.log(decodeURIComponent(r.body)));
}

module.exports.help = {
name: "test"
}
```

Comment: You should get a body of: "O hello there"